# How to remove "Export" action menu?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

I would like to remove "Export" in action menu in Odoo 14 Community Edition.

I want to remove it for all views at once if possible; otherwise, one by one for each required model or view would be fine.

[image: Export action menu]

I tried:

```
<xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="export_xlsx">false</attribute>
</xpath>
```

in individual model. Doesn't work.

Also tried overwriting the Sidebar in javascript. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it using this js code

```js
odoo.define('disable_export', function (require) {
"use strict";

const ListView = require('web.ListView');
const ListController = require('web.ListController');

ListView.include({
  init: function (viewInfo, params) {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.controllerParams.activeActions.export_xlsx = false;
  }
})

ListController.include({
  _getActionMenuItems: function (state) {
    this.isExportEnable = false;
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})

})
```

Comment: I tried your code as-is. The Export button in action menu is still showing.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I have updated my answer with the working part already tested. I see that you have found a similar solution

Answer (score 2):

Odoo will only show the `Export` option if the user belongs to the [Access to export feature](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_controller.js#L71-L73) group.

To hide the export option, just remove the user from the list

*Overriding the Action menus (previously called [Sidebar](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/components/action_menus.js#L13)) or the list controller will make the export group obsolete*

Comment: Do you have a solution without removing the user from the group because I need the group but I don't want the user to see the option?

Comment: You can override the `_getActionMenuItems` as you did but set the `isExportEnable` to `false` before calling super so Odoo will not add the `Export` option to other action items

Comment: So, the updated part from aekis.dev is a better version of mine, right?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for this problem.

```
odoo.define('remove_export_button', function (require) {
  "use strict";
  
  var core = require('web.core');
  var ListController = require('web.ListController');
  ListController.include({
    /**
     * @override
     * @private
     */
    _getActionMenuItems: function (state) {
      let actionMenus = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
      if (actionMenus?.items){
        actionMenus.items.other = actionMenus?.items?.other.filter(menu => menu.description !== 'Export');
      }
      return actionMenus;
    },
  });
});
```

It works for all views at once.